# List becoming empty on its own

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue with JSEngine:

1. I have a map of list (keys are strings and value is list).
2. I add a new key and list to map in a method named `addEventListener`.
3. I then access this list in another method `dispatchEvent`, where the list seems to be empty: which should not be the case (or what I don't expect).

I have created a dummy program that simulates the situation I am stuck at:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

//Dummy event target, which maintains a map of events and its subscribers list
struct EventTarget{
    //key is event type and value is list of subscribers
    map<const char*,list<int>>* subscribersForEvent;

    //checks if an event type is present the subscribersForEvent map
    int doContainsEvent(const char* event){
        return !(subscribersForEvent->find(event)==subscribersForEvent->end());
    }
};

/**
 * Simple context for storing Event target
*/
struct JSContext{
    EventTarget* target;
};

//creates event target in the given context
void constructEventTarget(JSContext* ctx){
    //will manage this memory in rest of my code
    ctx->target = (EventTarget*)malloc(sizeof(ctx->target));
    //will manage this **new** memory in rest of my code: don't worry about releasing it
    ctx->target->subscribersForEvent=new map<const char*,list<int>>;

    std::cout << "target created: "<< ctx->target << std::endl;
}

//adds event listener to the context
void addEventListener(JSContext* ctx,const char* type, int subscriber){
    auto et = ctx->target;
    std::cout << "target received: "<< et << std::endl;
    if(!et->doContainsEvent(type)){
        list<int> l;
        (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type]=l;
    }
    auto l = (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type];
    l.insert(l.end(),subscriber);
    std::cout << "List address1: "<< &l << " and size: "<<l.size()<< std::endl;
}

//dispatches event to respective subscribers
void dispatchEvent(JSContext* ctx,const char* type){
    auto et = ctx->target;
    if(et->doContainsEvent(type)){
        auto l = (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type];
        std::cout << "List address2: "<< &l << " and size: "<<l.size()<< std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
            std::cout << "Calling subscriber: "<< i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    JSContext context;
    JSContext* ctx=&context;
    constructEventTarget(ctx);
    const char* eventType="bye";
    addEventListener(ctx,eventType,1);
    dispatchEvent(ctx,eventType);

    return 0;
}
```

Current output of this program is:

```
target created: 0x55555556feb0
target received: 0x55555556feb0
List address1: 0x7fffffffd8d0 and size: 1
List address2: 0x7fffffffd8d0 and size: 0
```

My expectation is that the list should have retained its size.

1. What mistake I am doing that list get empty when called from different methods.
2. And how to fix this ?

Expected output:

```
target created: 0x55555556feb0
target received: 0x55555556feb0
List address1: 0x7fffffffd8d0 and size: 1
List address2: 0x7fffffffd8d0 and size: 1
```

Comment: What is the problem, more specifically?

Comment: you have 2 different things called 'l' in that method

Comment: @tadman I have created a list in `method1` and attached to a map as its value. And then I am accessing that list in another method, where the list seems to be empty. I was expecting it to be not empty as I have not calld any empty method.

Comment: @pm100 but they are in different scopes. The first `l` is created if not present. the scond l is same one which either got created or is present.

Comment: Yousa makin' copies! Edit one copy and the other copy sees nothing!

Comment: The more I look at this code, the more questions I have, as it's all rather confused and non-standard. `malloc` does not belong here, this is C++. Further, stuff like `(*et->subscribersForEvent)[type]` is just downright strange, that's not supposed to happen. It is far from clear why that `map` is dynamically allocated in the first place. You should probably *not* do that.

Comment: @user4581301 if you see output the memory address for maps and list is same. I don't think copy is created.

Comment: Tip: Use `new`, or better, a pointer wrapper like `smart_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. You allocate all kinds of memory here, and recklessly [disregard your responsibility to release it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: `auto l = (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type];` <- `l` is copy. `l.insert(l.end(),subscriber);` <- `subscriber` inserted in copy. `(*et->subscribersForEvent)[type]` unchanged.

Comment: Fun fact: When you use `[]` to access a `map` and the key doesn't exist, the map automatically makes the entry. That means `if(!et->doContainsEvent(type)){ list<int> l; (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type]=l; }` came free with `auto l = (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type];`

Comment: `int doContainsEvent` is actually `bool`. You're doing C++ with a very heavy C accent here, especially the pervasive use of `const char*` instead of, say, something more sensible like `const std::string&`.

Comment: The addresses are likely the same because of dumb luck. Because `l` is freed when the function returns the space is available for reuse by the next call. Give `auto & l = (*et->subscribersForEvent)[type];` and use `l` as a reference to the `list` in the `map`. That's most likely what you're after here.

Comment: @user4581301 yes `auto l=` is creating a copy and that is the problem. That solved my problem. Can you please post  it as answer , I will accept the answer.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes your suggestion is right, please post it as asnwer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not touching this one because I have to make too many guesses on how to clean up all of the other bugs in the code that you have yet to ask about. And some might not even BE bugs. For example, `map<const char*,list<int>>` is not going to key on the given string. It will key on the **address** of the string. `(*et->subscribersForEvent)["Bill"]` will not serve up the same object as `(*et->subscribersForEvent)["Bill"]` if both of the `"Bill"`s are stored in different locations, something the tools may or may not be able to recognize and optimize out.